# NoMethodError in Books#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

```
    I am getting the following error I am new to ruby and rails

    I am using Rails4 with eclipse plugin the error is 
    NoMethodError in Books#show 

    undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

    Extracted source (around line #3):  
    @book.subject.name I used associations in the model book which is belongs_to association with subject model.
    <h1><%= @book.title %></h1>
    <p><strong>Price: </strong> $<%= @book.price %><br />
    <strong>Subject: </strong> <%= link_to @book.subject.name,    #line number 3
    :action => "show_subjects", :id => @book.subject.id %><br />
    <strong>Created Date:</strong> <%= @book.created_at %><br />
    </p>

    app/views/books/show.erb:3:in `_app_views_books_show_erb___1047429498_14766720'
    actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
    activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
    actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'

    routes.rb file is

    LibrarayWebApplication::Application.routes.draw do
        get 'books/list'
        get 'books/new'
        post 'books/create'
        post 'books/update'
      get 'books/list'
       get 'books/show'
       get 'books/show_subjects'
      get 'books/edit'
        get 'books/delete'
          get 'books/update'
     get 'books/show_subjects'
    end

    my migrations files are

    books.rb

    class Books < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def self.up
         create_table :books do |t|
      t.column :title, :string, :limit => 32, :null => false
      t.column :price, :float
      t.column :subject_id, :integer
      t.column :description, :text
      t.column :created_at, :timestamp
         end
      end

      def self.down
        drop_table :books
      end
    end

    subjects.rb

    class Subjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def self.up
          create_table :subjects do |t|
           t.column :name, :string
        end
        Subject.create :name => "Physics"
        Subject.create :name => "Mathematics"
        Subject.create :name => "Chemistry"
        Subject.create :name => "Psychology"
        Subject.create :name => "Geography"
      end

      def self.down
          drop_table :subjects
      end
    end

    my controller files is

    class BooksController < ApplicationController
       def list
          @books = Book.find(:all)
       end
       def show
          @book = Book.find(params[:id])
       end
       def new
          @book = Book.new
          @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
       end
      #  private 
       def book_params
       params.require(:book).permit(:title,:price,:subject,:description)
       end
       def create
          @book = Book.new(book_params)
          if @book.save
                redirect_to :action => 'list'
          else
                @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
                render :action => 'new'
          end
       end


          def edit
          @book = Book.find(params[:id])
          @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
       end
      def update
            @book = Book.find(params[:id])

            if @book.update_attributes(book_params)
              redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @book
            else
              @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
              render :action => 'edit'
            end
          end
       def delete
          Book.find(params[:id]).destroy
          redirect_to :action => 'list'
       end
       def show_subjects
          @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
       end
    end

    show.erb file is
    I used associations in the model book which is belongs_to association with subject model.
    <h1><%= @book.title %></h1>
    <p><strong>Price: </strong> $<%= @book.price %><br />
        <strong>Subject: </strong> <%= link_to @book.subject.name, #this line I am getting error
    :action => "show_subjects", :id => @book.subject.id %><br />
    <strong>Created Date:</strong> <%= @book.created_at %><br />
    </p>
    <p><%= @book.description %></p>
    <hr />
    <%= link_to 'Back', {:action => 'list'} %>

    show_subjects file is

    <h1><%= @subject.name -%></h1>
    <ul>
    <% @subject.books.each do |c| %>
    <li><%= link_to c.title, :action => "show", :id => c.id -%></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>

    I have two models 
    book.erb

    class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :subject
       validates_presence_of :title
      validates_numericality_of :price, :message=>"Error Message"
    end

I made associations between the models in book model I used belongs_to and in subject model I used has_many but I am getting that error If I remove the subject in show.erb the application working fine but when I include that line it showing that no such method
```

I made associations between the models in book model I used belongs_to and in subject model I used has_many but I am getting that error If I remove the subject in show.erb the application working fine but when I include that line it showing that no such method
          I made associations between the models in book model I used belongs_to and in subject model I used has_many but I am getting that error If I remove the subject in show.erb the application working fine but when I include that line it showing that no such method

```
    subject.erb
    class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :books
    end
```

I wrote @book.subject.name if @book.subject this statement avoided the error but it unable to retrieving the subject name from the database

Comment: In show.erb file I used <strong>Subject :</strong> <%= @book.subject.try(:name)%><br /> this command worked fine and it showing like Subject:          ,but it does not retrieving the subject data.I want to display like Subject:subjectname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the undefined method error because you don't have a subject for that particular book. In other words, you should check for the presence of a book subject before actually calling book.subject.name.

P.s. I would change your subject migration (ditch the Subject.create '...' part) and use resources :books for your routes instead of defining all routes individually.

Comment: in subject migration I have subject.create na??

Comment: If I use resources:books is it required to write get/post or no need

Comment: There is no sense in creating subjects within your migration, that is actually bad practice and should be avoided whenever possible. If you use resources :books you don't have to define all CRUD routes. The custom routes can be defined by using member do ... end or collection do ... end within the resources :books block.

Comment: I removed that code Subject:create even its showing the error in show.erb earlier error. I want to display the each subject name to the user

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You can use book.subject.name, but you have to add an if condition to make sure book.subject is not nil (as in: book.subject.present?)

Answer (score 0):

In show.html.erb instead of `@book.subject.name` write as `@book.subject.try(:name)` or `@book.subject.name if @book.subject`

Comment: I wouldn't use try unless you have a really good reason to do so. The last option is more clear and better in my opinion. That is why I also recommended this solution in my answer. Try makes your code more flexible then it should be.